# How to implement multiple RPS logout for an OP?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I'm currently trying to implement multiple RPS (Relay Party) logout for an OP (OpenID Provider) using Spring's [new plugin for OAuth2](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server). More details [here](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/openid-connect-logout-eccc73df758f#facc).

Basically my SPA(Single Page Application) frontend makes a request to logout OP endpoint. Right now I want to log out all the RP's from that session.
I saw that a possible strategy is to define the SID (Session ID) attribute in the *access_token* to make this binding between the session and token.
But I saw that there is no implementation for this.

The OP runs in high availability with multiple instances, with session passivation and stick session active.

At this first moment I need this SID information in *access_token*.
Previously this was done through [TokenEnhancer](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt-legacy#enhancer), but I didn't see how to do it in this new version of the plugin.